# second and third drop not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `div` box: `.box001`, `.box002`.

When I drag and drop `.box002` with `id="1"` to another `div` - `.box001` with `id="11"` dragged element deletes `ondrop` also `background-color` becomes `none`,

When I drag and drop second drag element, `.box002` with `id="2"` to another `div` - `.box001` with `id="20"`, and another `.box002` with `id="3"` to another `div` - .`box001` with `id="30"` I can't get the desired effect as in first one, also make `background-color` to `none` in `.box002`.

How do I get a perfect working drop cycle which check `id` of `.box001` and `.box002`?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var i = 0;
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el); // deleting drag item

  document.getElementsByClassName('box001')[i].style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
  document.getElementById('11').innerHTML = ''; // which box p  should blank 
  i = i + 1;;
}
```

```css
.box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font: 70px;
  ;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/*margin: -50px;
right: 20px;
float: left;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;

}*/
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
  <p id="11"> 8:30</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="20">
  <p id="12">12:25</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="30">
  <p id="13">01:00</p>
</div>


<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="3" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: i want to get the same drop effect as happned with blue box with time 6:30 to rest of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `i` outside the `drop` function. Now, each drop set the `i` to 0, so each time you affect the same `div`.

```js
var i = 0;

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  alert(data);
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild(el); // deleting drag item

  document.getElementsByClassName('box001')[i].style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
  document.getElementById('11').innerHTML = ''; // which box p  should blank 
  i = i + 1;;
}
```

```css
//.box001 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #42e0fd;
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font: 70px;
  ;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: xx-small;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.box002 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/*margin: -50px;
right: 20px;
float: left;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;

}*/
```

```html
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
  <p id="11"> 8:30</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="20">
  <p id="12">12:25</p>
</div>
<div class="box001" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="30">
  <p id="13">01:00</p>
</div>


<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="1" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" draggable="true" id="3" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
</div>
```